# "Change" for the future?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a single-term for the *Change* or *Update* for the future?

I am currently developing an application where the user will add an entry with an effective date but I am having a difficulty labeling that button.

Let's say I label the button as

> Add New Entry

This doesn't seem right because the user will not add a new entry on the list of active entries but rather he/she will create an entry that will be active on a certain date, or one-at-a-time.

> Update Entry

This will not work because the action will not immediately update the entry, the entry will change on the effective date specified by the user.

What is an appropriate label for such button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have another button to add an entry to the current list, having a button labeled "New Entry" might be the most straightforward. It would be inferred by the flow that when you create a new entry, you must also specify a start-date for it.

Comment: This is really the most straightforward! Although @coleopterist answer is also correct, but I think it might sound odd for some _entry_, for example _"Add Scheduled Schedule."_

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest something along the lines of *Add scheduled entry*.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes into mind is *enqueue*, which is "to put into a queue". However, this is not exactly what you want.

You could also use *defer*:

> defer implies a deliberate putting off to a later time .

Or *postpone*:

> postpone implies an intentional deferring usually to a definite time

Comment: Thanks, but the terms you give are not that _simple_ enough to be easily understood by my users. Do you know any other, more _simpler_, English terms?

Answer (score 1):

What about *Prospective Entry*?

Alternatively you could use *Upcoming Entry* or even simply *Future Entry*.

If the listed item is always the only one in this category, you could say *Next Entry*